# How probabilities are calculated in MS SQL Server Analysis Services - Decision Tree model?

Tags: ssas, probability, decision-tree

I am a new user of MS SSAS models and I'd like to know how the probabilities are being calculated within the node distribution of Decision tree model.

**Example:**

I've created a model for sample data (***'Iris'***) using SSAS decision trees and inferred that probability values appeared were irreleveant to data and so, I'd like to know how these values are being calculated.

For your reference, please find the screenshot from the following,

[image]

From the above, we could infer that total cases supported by the node is **"42"**, so

```
Species      Cases     Usual probability calculation       SSAS probability
                              (expected)       

setosa         0            0 / 26 => 0                    0.0235988200589971
versicolor     4            4 / 42 => 0.095238             0.112094395280236
virginica     38           38 / 42 => 0.904762             0.864306784660767
```

It will be more helpful, if you could help me with this. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can anyone help me with this please ?

Answer (score 0):

From the documents, it appears that the prior node is being acounted for as well:

> Probability = (support for state + support for prior state) / (node support plus the prior node support)

You can check it out in the Probabilities section of this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/data-mining/mining-model-content-for-decision-tree-models-analysis-services-data-mining?view=asallproducts-allversions#bkmk_NodeDist_Discrete